# Comment analyser « Il est tard » ?

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

Comment analyser cete phrase :

> Il est tard.

- *il* = sujet apparent
- *est* = verbe copule
- *tard* = sujet réel

Est-ce que c'est correct  ?

Comment: **Tard est !** ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre C'est parce qu'on dit ça en ma langue maternelle lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le sens de « il est [tard](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tard), il se fait (*commencer à être*) [tard](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tard) » est une indication temporelle à l'effet que « l'heure est avancée » (TLFi) ; en remaniant l'adverbe *tard* en adjectif on pourrait sans doute dire que « l'heure est [tardive](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tardive) ». Et ce serait dans tous les cas l'heure qui serait le sujet « réel » ou « logique » de cette transformation de la phrase en question, quoique cette analyse s'avère hasardeuse. Indépendamment de la qualification de réel ou apparent, il est difficile de concevoir qu'un adverbe puisse être sujet vu sa [nature](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4328)... Pour ces raisons l'affirmation à l'effet que *tard* serait sujet réel m'apparaît erronée.

---

Par ailleurs, malgré une certaine similitude, vu le pronom impersonnel *il* utilisé pour des fins grammaticales plutôt que sémantiques (quoique absent avec expressions figées : « M'est avis qu'il va faire de l'orage », Arland), ça ne signifie pas que l'on puisse procéder à la même analyse avec les verbes essentiellement impersonnels exprimant des phénomènes météorologiques comme *pleuvoir, tonner, neiger, venter, bruiner* etc. sauf quand ils expriment une condition particulière du phénomène et qu'ils sont accompagnés d'une séquence nominale (*il neige de gros flocons*), ce qui diffère conceptuellement de l'emploi personnel de ces mêmes verbes (« Eau, quand donc pleuvras-tu ? Quand tonneras-tu, foudre ? », Baudelaire) ; voir *Le bon usage* § 231, 235, 782-787, excellent.

Answer (score 2):

« Il » est un pronom impersonnel. http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/341.html

« Être » est employé impersonnellement. http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/340.html#2

les auxiliaires être et avoir dans les tournures présentatives il est et il y a.

- Il est treize heures.
- Il y a longtemps que je n'étais pas venu ici. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_impersonnel

Les constructions impersonnelles ([encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_impersonnel))

Les constructions impersonnelles associent le pronom sujet impersonnel « il » à un verbe connaissant des emplois personnels. Une construction impersonnelle résulte toujours de la transformation d'une construction personnelle (ex: Cinq centimètres de neige sont tombés >> Il est tombé cinq centimètres de neige). On appelle « séquence » le groupe de mots qui suit le verbe et qui correspond au sujet dans la phrase personnelle. Cette séquence constitue le sujet réel de la phrase, alors que le pronom impersonnel « il » en constitue le sujet apparent.

« Tard » n'est pas un sujet réel. Un sujet réel ne peut être qu'un nom, un pronom, un infinitif ou une proposition subordonnée introduite par « que ». https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-86452.php

Dans ce cas, certains grammairiens n'accepte pas que « tard » soit un sujet réel. https://www.cordial.fr/grammaire/manuels/SUJ_APP.htm